# Continually scanning a value in memory without using an infinite loop

Tags: c#, infinite-loop

I'm scanning outside program's memory.

The code looks like that:

```
while (true)
{
  read(x)
  if (x changed since last check)
    {
    x = new value;
    .
    .
    .
    }
Thread.Sleep(0);
}
```

I believe it's a big waste for CPU to keep on reading 1 value all the time.
Unfrotunately, I'cant give there a bigger sleep. Is there any possible way to lower CPU usage and keep the functionality of my prog?

Here's the function I'm using to read process memory:

```
            //      BOOL ReadProcessMemory(
            //          HANDLE hProcess,              // handle to the process
            //          LPCVOID lpBaseAddress,        // base of memory area
            //          LPVOID lpBuffer,              // data buffer
            //          SIZE_T nSize,                 // number of bytes to read
            //          SIZE_T * lpNumberOfBytesRead  // number of bytes read
            //          );
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern Int32 ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [In, Out] byte[] buffer, UInt32 size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    public byte[] ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr MemoryAddress, uint bytesToRead, out int bytesRead)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead];

        IntPtr ptrBytesRead;
        ProcessMemoryReaderApi.ReadProcessMemory(m_hProcess, MemoryAddress, buffer, bytesToRead, out ptrBytesRead);

        bytesRead = ptrBytesRead.ToInt32();

        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Without knowing what the underlying problem is, it will be difficult to offer solutions.

Comment: How is `x` being read? You might be able to multi-thread and use a `ManualResetEvent`

Comment: I'm reading x out of memory of outside process. This scanning is running in a different thread.

Comment: @Patryk how are you reading the memory? Please show us the code of `read` as there could be a way to detect a value changed instead of poling using the library you are using to read the memory.

Comment: Is modifying the other application a problem? Are you looking for changes that happen often or very seldom?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've pasted memory reading function to my question. [at]AdamD, Unforutnately, I can't edit outside app

Comment: Why is it that you can't use a bigger value for sleep?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you put the code in a timer, and suspend processing (with DoEvents() that will halt the current process until next iteration) until the other program at least got a change to update itself.

That would keep the system running.

In lower level languages checking if memory has changed is often done in loops as well. The processor will not actively announce changes in memory. The memory is not a input, like a keyboard is.

You could even start this code in a Thread an give it low priority with thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal; to ease the system even more.

Doing so you might miss out on a change that was done. So if that is important it is important to atleast have the same priority as the other program.